# Is there a better way than event listening for communication between different objects?

Tags: javascript, oop, event-handling

Let's say we have an emitter object implementing some logic and another different type object that implements some other logic depending on the events triggered by the emitter object. I guess, we can simply solve this by using function[pointer]s in the emitter and change their target by using a function that adds listener functions of the listener object like the code in the following. Even we can remove it. Like the DOM events, I can say.

Can you suggest a better way for this newbie from some other profession previously? Thanks in advance.

```js
class Emitter {
  constructor() {
    this.event1 = this.empty;
    this.event2 = this.empty;
  }

  empty(){}

  someEmmitterLogic(input) {
    // arbitrary logic here before event1 occurs
    this.event1({message:"produced at event1", b:1});
    // maybe event2 can also occur here
    this.event2({message:"produced at event2", d:2});
  }

  addEvent(event, listener) {
    switch (event) {
      case "event1":
        this.event1 = listener;
        break;
      case "event2":
        this.event2 = listener;
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Sorry, we don't emit this event.");
    }
  }

  removeEvent(event) {
    switch (event) {
      case "event1":
        this.event1 = this.empty;
        break;
      case "event2":
        this.event2 = this.empty;
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Sorry, cannot remove an event we are not emitting.");
    }
  }  
}

class Listener{
    constructor(){
// Simple listeners outputting the event object to the console 
    this.listener1 = (e) => console.log(e.message);
    this.listener2 = (e) => console.log(e.message);
}
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const emitter = new Emitter();
const listener = new Listener();

console.log("STATUS: not listening emitter");
emitter.someEmmitterLogic();

// Add listeners
emitter.addEvent("event1", listener.listener1);
emitter.addEvent("event2", listener.listener2);

console.log("STATUS: started listening emitter");
emitter.someEmmitterLogic();

console.log("say we don't need event1 anymore, let's remove it");
emitter.removeEvent("event1");
console.log("STATUS: listening event2 only");
emitter.someEmmitterLogic();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

[Fiddle of the code above](https://jsfiddle.net/demiryavuz1973/qLcmnrow/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Events

Using events in this way is a well-established way to provide this kind of communication. If you look for existing implementations of event emitters like [Node.js's](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#class-eventemitter) or search for "publish/subscribe," you'll find a lot of prior art you can draw on.

Some notes:

- Usually, you want to have a set of event handlers rather than allowing just one.
- Generally, the emitter would wrap calls to event handlers in `try`/`catch` blocks so that a handler throwing an error doesn't prevent the emitter code from continuing to do its job (which is typically just to notify listeners of the event).
- Some systems (including the DOM's) provide the same event object to all listeners, allowing a bit of cross-talk between them. Uncontrolled cross-talk is probably a bad idea, but some form of controlled cross-talk may be useful.
- Similarly some systems (including the DOM's) provide a way for the event listeners to cancel the event, preventing it reaching other listeners.

### Coroutines

Another way to do communication along these lines when there's sequence (in a very broad sense) to be observed is to use [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine). In JavaScript, coroutines can be implemented using [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), which are most easily created via generator functions. A generator is an object that produces and consumes values in response to a call to its `next` method.

Here's a really simple generator that only produces (doesn't consume) values:

```js
// Generator function (note the `*` after `function`) returns
// a generator. This generator provides a series of values in
// a given range (inclusive).
function* range(from = 1, to = 10) {
    console.log("Generator: Starting");
    for (let value = from; value <= to; ++value) {
        console.log(`Generator: Ready with value ${value}`);
        yield value;
    }
}

// A popular way to consume generators (and iterables in general) is
// the `for-of` loop. When the generator/iterable is infinite
// as in our case, you need to be sure to break out of it at some point.
for (const value of range(1, 5)) {
    console.log(`for-of:    Received ${value}`);
}
console.log(`Done`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note how the logic of the generator (really simple logic in this case, a `for` loop) and the consumer of it (again really simple, the `for-of` loop) are intermixed.

Generators are a great way to produce iterables like that one, but they can also *consume* values that are pushed to them. To push values to a generator, you call `next` directly rather than implicitly. Here's another simple example of a generator, but this one both produces *and* consumes values — it's a simple 1-100 number guessing game, with the generator in charge of picking the number and telling you how good your guess is:

```js
function* hiddenNumber(from = 1, to = 100) {
    console.log("Generator: Starting");
    const size = (to - from + 1);
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * size) + from;
    // console.log("cheat: " + num);
    let guess = yield `Pick a number between ${from} and ${to} (inclusive)`;
    while (guess !== num) {
        if (guess < num) {
            if (Math.abs(num - guess) >= size / 2) {
                guess = yield "REALLY low";
            } else {
                guess = yield "too low";
            }
        } else if (guess > num) {
            if (Math.abs(num - guess) >= size / 2) {
                guess = yield "REALLY high";
            } else {
                guess = yield "too high";
            }
        }
    }
    return "you got it!";
}

const prompt = document.getElementById("prompt");
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const doGuess = () => {
    const num = input.valueAsNumber;
    const result = game.next(num);
    const answer = result.value;
    prompt.textContent = answer;
    if (result.done) {
        button.disabled = true;
    } else {
        input.focus();
        input.select();
    }
};
const game = hiddenNumber();
prompt.textContent = game.next().value;
button.addEventListener("click", doGuess);
input.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        doGuess();
    }
});
input.select();
```

```html
<p id="prompt"></p>
<input id="input" type="number" value="0" step="1">
<input id="button" type="button" value="Guess">
```

You can see the interaction of the code using it (`doGuess`) with the generator's logic.

Coroutines are really useful, but (IMHO) probably less general than an event emitter.

Comment: (FWIW, I go into generator functions along with everything else from ES2015-ES2020 in detail in my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. This widened my perspective.  Implemented it too. Looks like populating objects into a manager object to exchange data will provide every means. I will obtain the book, it means a lot to me as I am in the early phases of my programming journey.

Comment: @user4234-483244-34 - I'm glad that helped! The book is targeted at intermediate JavaScript programmers so parts may be a bit ahead of where you are right now (or not!), but from the question, I think you'll be fine. Happy coding!

Comment: I was reading the comments about the book and realized that I will need some time to adjust myself for it. Hopefully, I will come to that point. Thanks again.